# Hibernate not returning expected mapping values

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

I have a database setup like this

```
tickets table
-------------
ticket_id
title
description
department_id
status_id
priority_id
assignee_id
creator_id

departments table
------------------
dep_id
dep_name

status table
------------
status_id
status_name

priority table
---------------
pr_id
pr_name

users table
-----------
u_id
username
password
salt
email
firstName
lastName
department_id
userlevel_id

userlevels table
-----------------
ul_id
ul_name
```

I'm trying to load all tickets from the ticket table using the following query:

```
SQLQuery q = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT t.*,d.*,s.*,p.*,u1.*, u2.*,a.* "
                    + "FROM tickets t "
                    + "INNER JOIN departments d ON t.department_id = d.dep_id "
                    + "INNER JOIN status s ON t.status_id = s.stat_id "
                    + "INNER JOIN priority p ON t.priority_id = p.pr_id "
                    + "INNER JOIN users u1 ON t.creator_id = u1.u_id "
                    + "INNER JOIN users u2 ON t.assignee_id = u2.u_id "
                    + "INNER JOIN attachments a ON t.tick_id = a.ticket_id "
                    + "WHERE assignee_id = ?");

            q.setInteger(0, assignee_id);
            q.addEntity("t", Ticket.class);
            q.addJoin("d", "t.department");
            q.addJoin("s", "t.status");
            q.addJoin("p", "t.priority");
            q.addJoin("u1", "t.creatorUser");
            q.addJoin("u2", "t.assignedUser");

            List<Object> tickets = q.list();
```

All the properties of the ticket are loading fine except the assigned user. What i think is happening is that the query is only returning the first user (creatorUser). creatorUser and assignedUser both belong to the users table, so hibernate is seeing duplicate column names and is only loading the first one. I'm not sure how to fix this issue... any help is appreciated, Thanks!!

Comment: Hibernate gives you a list of all ojects the query returns! (Not only the first one). Have you tred the query on command line?

Comment: I see... then its only loading the first user.. No i haven't but im sure i would get the same output...

Comment: Are all tables filled that you join? Why you add the lines after setInteger?

Comment: yes all the tables are filled..those lines are hibernate methods that allow it to map the results to the objects correctly